# trying to get value from models. octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

i want to retrieve records of one model into another model in repeater in dropdown.
i have to model one is POST and another is BLOCK, records from block model shows in dropdown inside of repeater in post model at backend and also saving it into post model

post ***yaml***

```
 repeater_data:
        label: Repeater
        prompt: 'Add new item'
        maxItems: '5'
        span: full
        type: repeater
        form:
            fields:
                blocks:
                    label: Dropdown
                    span: full
                    type: dropdown
                    options: blocksToAdd
```

***post.php*** model

```
 protected $jsonable = ['blocks'];

    public function blocksToAdd()
    {
        $blocks = Block::pluck('title');

        //$jenkebOptions= [''];
        foreach ($blocks as $item) {

            // json decoding
            $decoded = json_decode($item, true);
            $jenkebOptions[] = $decoded;
            log::info($decoded);

        }
    return $jenkebOptions;

}
```

thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to `json_decode` or am i missing something

In normal scenario, you need to return array of `values and title` pair

```
public function blocksToAdd()
{
    return Block::pluck('title','id');
}
```

just do this it will return array

```
[1 => 'title 1', 2 => 'title 2']
```

and now in drop-down title[title] is visible respectively its value[id]

> if you need title as value ind base then you can do like this

```
public function blocksToAdd()
{
    $blockTitles = Block::pluck('id','title');
    $blockTitlesArray = []; 
    foreach($blockTitles as $title) {
        $blockTitlesArray[$title] = $title;
    }
    return $blockTitlesArray; 
}
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: do you know about contectplus plugin, data are retrieved and show in dropdown after selecting one of option in database if i do your code then it stores id of title okay so is there any way to retrieve record based on id which is store in database and record comes from another model called Block

Comment: updated section if you need to store title you can use updated code for `title`